# AC and blower won't run at the same time

Tags: hvac, blower

AC was running yesterday, suddenly the blower just stopped. I turn the AC off, the blower starts and runs fine. I turn the AC on, the blower stops immediately. Both the AC and the blower won't run at the same time, but work fine independently. The filter is clean, the condensation hose is clean, the thermostat connections look fine. I have not opened the condenser (Goodman) as I'm not a tech or anything.

Comment: If you run your fan all the time(on many thermostats this means "Fan = On" vs. "Fan = Auto"), it may still be under A/C control when the A/C is on. So that points to a relay (or similar) in the A/C control board. If you have central heat (e.g., natural gas) using the same air handler, does that work? (Just to test - obviously you won't want to run the heat much if is 95F outside).

Comment: In most installations, the A/C unit is unable to control the fan. Thus, the thermostat calls for "fan" whenever it calls for "A/C".    That mechanically happens by the thermostat shunting R to G (to call for fan) and R to Y (to call for A/C).